# URL Rewrite with query parameter is not working

Tags: url-rewriting, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

The following url-rewirte rule is not working,

```
<rule>
    <from>^/coupon.do\?cc=([A-Z]{4})$</from>
    <to last="true">/services/1.0/coupon/$1</to>
</rule>
```

redirect from /coupon.do?cc=ABCD to /services/1.0/coupon/ABCD is not working.

Please let me know my mistake.

Comment: Have you tried to add ```use-query-string = true``` in your ```<urlrewrite>``` element? So that you have <urlrewrite user-query-string="true">

Answer (score 0):

Default `type` for `<to>` is forward, that said for redirect you have to change it explicitly to have `type="redirect"`.

However, to have URL matched to your pattern, you need to add `use-query-string="true"` to your `<urlrewrite>` opening tag. So this should work,

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">

    <rule match-type="regex">
        <from>^/coupon.do\?cc=([A-Z]{4})$</from>
        <to type="redirect" last="true">/services/1.0/coupon/$1</to>
    </rule>

</urlrewrite>
```

And don't forget to have `match-type="regexp"` for your rule.